# Mongodb Aggregation Average on selected array values

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, average

I have two collections in MongoDB. One is User collection and Course collections.

My Real data in the various collection regards the course

**Course collection:**

```
{
    "course": {
        "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
        "cmodules": [
            "612f5612dc3813068b76646c"
        "612f561adc3813e7a27664f6",
        ],
        "title": "C++ Complete Course"
    }
}
```

**Module Collection:**

```
{
    "cmodules": [
        {
            "_id": "612f561adc3813e7a27664f6",
            "topics": [
                "612f561bdc381332647664fd"
                "612f5615dc3813d8a47664bb",
                "612f5617dc38130e017664de"
            ],
            "title": "Welcome to C++",
            "desc": "C++ Introduction",
        },
        {
            "_id": "612f5612dc3813068b76646c",
            "topics": [
                "612f5612dc3813ef8c766473"
                "612f561cdc38132d73766514",
                "612f561fdc3813ad1676652d"
            ],
            "title": "Introduction to STL",
            "desc": "Learn Standard template library",
        }
    ]
}
```

**Topic Collection:**

```
{
    "topics": [
        {
            "_id": "612f561bdc381332647664fd",
            "units": [
                "612f561bdc3813154b766503",
                "612f561cdc3813feba76650b"
            ],
            "order": 0,
            "title": "Session 1",
        },
        {
            "_id": "612f561cdc38132d73766514",
            "units": [
                "612f561ddc381317b176651a",
                "612f561ddc38135e3a766520",
                "612f561edc3813bf45766526"
            ],
            "title": "Session 2",
        },
        {
            "_id": "612f561fdc3813ad1676652d",
            "units": [
                "612f5620dc3813491b766533",
                "612f5620dc3813b5f2766539",
                "612f5621dc381387d976653f"
            ],
            "title": "Session 3",
        }
    ]
}
```

I am tracking all the list of units id accessed by the student in an array(`learnedUnits`) at the user details.

The unit list read by the student is stored in the user's collection.

```
"learnedUnits": [
                    "612f5608dc38133ee6766411",
                    "61322aa16c985ae927308a82",
                    "612f5608dc3813268a766417",
                    "612f5609dc38137cd776641d"
                ],
```

Course collection that has a set of modules and every module will have a set of topics and every topic will have a set of units.
Also, I am tracking all the units ID which is read by the user in the user's collections. By doing some aggregation pipeline, I arrive with the following.

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5fd5c105694d122f4837fa0f",
        "learningPath": {
            "historyCourses": {
                "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
                "startedAt": "2021-09-03T13:58:32.071Z",
                "learnedUnits": [
                    "612f5608dc38133ee6766411",
                    "61322aa16c985ae927308a82",
                    "612f5608dc3813268a766417",
                    "612f5609dc38137cd776641d"
                ],
                "course": {
                    "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
                    "cmodules": {
                        "_id": "612f5612dc3813068b76646c",
                        "topics": [
                            {
                                "_id": "612f5612dc3813ef8c766473",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f5613dc381382797664ac",
                                    "612f5614dc38139a927664b2"
                                ],
                                "title": "Session 1",
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "612f5615dc3813d8a47664bb",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f5615dc38131ee17664c8",
                                    "612f5616dc381317fa7664ce",
                                    "612f5616dc38132ac37664d5"
                                ],
                                "title": "Session 2",
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "612f5617dc38130e017664de",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f5618dc381399cf7664e4",
                                    "612f5618dc38138e367664ea",
                                    "612f5619dc38137fe87664f0"
                                ],
                                "title": "Session 3",
                            }
                        ],
                        "title": "Welcome to C++",
                        "desc": "C++ Introduction",
                    },
                    "title": "C++ Complete Course",
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fd5c105694d122f4837fa0f",
        "learningPath": {
            "historyCourses": {
                "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
                "startedAt": "2021-09-03T13:58:32.071Z",
                "learnedUnits": [
                    "612f5608dc38133ee6766411",
                    "61322aa16c985ae927308a82",
                    "612f5608dc3813268a766417",
                    "612f5609dc38137cd776641d"
                ],
                "course": {
                    "_id": "612f5605dc3813a3717663fe",
                    "cmodules": {
                        "_id": "612f561adc3813e7a27664f6",
                        "topics": [
                            {
                                "_id": "612f561bdc381332647664fd",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f561bdc3813154b766503",
                                    "612f561cdc3813feba76650b"
                                ],
                                "order": 0,
                                "title": "Session 1",
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "612f561cdc38132d73766514",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f561ddc381317b176651a",
                                    "612f561ddc38135e3a766520",
                                    "612f561edc3813bf45766526"
                                ],
                                "title": "Session 2",
                            },
                            {
                                "_id": "612f561fdc3813ad1676652d",
                                "units": [
                                    "612f5620dc3813491b766533",
                                    "612f5620dc3813b5f2766539",
                                    "612f5621dc381387d976653f"
                                ],
                                "title": "Session 3",
                            }
                        ],
                        "title": "Introduction to STL",
                        "desc": "Learn Standard template library",
                    },
                    "title": "C++ Complete Course",
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I want to find how much the user learned against the course by using the `learnedUnits` field above. Average against the total units with the `learnedUnits` field.

Is there any way to find the average of completed units in the above collection?

Comment: can you give sample initital data in, and how you want them to become? because you want the avg and, we see only an array with IDs, probably you want something like lookup and then avg

Comment: @Takis_ I added real data on how the course is stored in the various collections and their relationship.